# can't make module "mod_dingaling" for freeswitch

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-wheezy

I am trying to follow the article listed below to make my Pi into a PBX:

http://raspberrypipbx.blogspot.ca/2012/12/using-google-voice-as-land-line.html?showComment=1394806601950#c2548040647034435813

I'm on the step where I'm supposed to make mod_dingaling by doing the following:

```
#make mod_dingaling-install
```

When I do that, I'm getting the following error:

No rule to make target 'mod_dingaling-install'.

**What I've done So Far:**

I've cross referenced another article that takes you through the freeswitch install, found here: 
https://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Mod_dingaling

I confirmed I have the module by doing the following:

```
apt-get install libssl-dev
```

The system returns with the message that libssl-dev is already the newest version.

I'm not sure how to fix this problem.  I've been googling the error message... haven't found anything relevant to me yet.  But I'll keep trying.  In the interim thought I'd post here to see if anyone had an idea.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to run each item separately.  So instead of:

```
#./bootstrap.sh && ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/freeswitch && make clean && make clean modwipe && make && make install
```

I ran

```
#./bootstrap.sh 
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/freeswitch
make clean
make clean modwipe 
make 
make install
```

Although I didn't notice any errors when running everything in one step, breaking it up individually allowed me to be explicit and watch step by step. 
It seems to be getting further now...

Answer (score 1):

When make says that there is no target, that means either that the Makefile isn't there at all, or that it doesn't contain the thing you want to do. It's not a problem with any of the system libraries, but something specifically with FreeSWITCH. I'd start by re-checking the bootstrap and configure line ran successfully:

```
#./bootstrap.sh && ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/freeswitch && make clean && make clean modwipe && make && make install
```

Then that you made the necessary changes to the /usr/src/freeswitch/modules.conf file to uncomment:

```
endpoints/mod_dingaling
```

(This means there should be no # in front of it.) After that hopefully make will run correctly. If it doesn't it seems there's a larger problem with FreeSWITCH.